# Camunda not creating RunTimeService bean

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, workflow-engine

Trying to run camunda with this configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "camunda.bpm.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class CamundaConfig {

    @Component
    public class ConfigureProcessEngineConfigurationPlugin extends AbstractProcessEnginePlugin {

        @Override
        public void preInit(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration) {
            processEngineConfiguration.getCustomPostBPMNParseListeners().add(taskEnhancingBpmParseListener());
            processEngineConfiguration.setDelegateInterceptor(skipDelegateInterceptor());
            processEngineConfiguration.setEnablePasswordPolicy(true);
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public SkipDelegateInterceptor skipDelegateInterceptor() {
        return new SkipDelegateInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskEnhancingBpmParseListener taskEnhancingBpmParseListener() {
        return new TaskEnhancingBpmParseListener(
            new LoggingUserTaskEndListener()
        );
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
camunda.bpm.admin-user.id=admin
camunda.bpm.admin-user.firstName=test
camunda.bpm.admin-user.lastName=test
camunda.bpm.admin-user.password=test123
camunda.bpm.database.schema-update=false
camunda.bpm.database.schema-name=camunda
camunda.bpm.database.table-prefix=camunda.
```

When I run my app I'm getting:

> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService' in your configuration.

I can't seem to figure out whats going wrong

Answer (score 0):

ConfigureProcessEngineConfigurationPlugin should be static.

```
@Component
public static class ConfigureProcessEngineConfigurationPlugin extends AbstractProcessEnginePlugin { ...
```

Comment: I was excluding  CamundaBpmAutoConfiguration.class and totally forgot about it. Removing that did the job